# Adding extra data to Percona audit log record

Tags: mysql, percona, audit-logging

I am looking into installing the Percona audit log over my MySQL Community edition installation. One thing I need to have is some extra data inside the record.

For example, I have a single `mysql` connection user `web`, but I have a number of application users (fully authenticated) that make all sorts of changes. For that purpose, on connection start, I `SET` the connection variable, populating it with the currently authenticated application user.

I cannot find anywhere in the docs whether is this kind of logging supported :-/

Is there a way to include *some* connection variables in a record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the answer at the Percona Community forum:

https://forums.percona.com/t/including-some-extra-data-in-audit-record/18401/3